# Strange array initialize expression?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, compiler-construction

What is the meaning of following Code? Code is from the regression test suite of GCC.

```
static char * name[] = {
   [0x80000000]  = "bar"
};
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In  C99  you can specify the array indices to assigned value, For example:

```
static char * name[] = {
   [3]  = "bar"  
};
```

is same as:

```
static char * name[] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, "bar"};
```

The size of array is four. Check an example code working at [ideaone](http://ideone.com/0oUb8Y). In your code  array size is `0x80000001` (its an hexadecimal number).
Note: Uninitialized elements initialized with `0`.

> #### [5.20 Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html):
>
> In ISO C99 you can give the elements in any order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and GNU C allows this as an extension in C89 mode as well. This extension is not implemented in GNU C++.
>   To specify an array index, write `[index] =` before the element value. For example,
>
> ```
>  int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
>  int a[6] = { 0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0 };
> ```

One more interesting declaration is possible in a GNU extension:

> An alternative syntax for this which has been obsolete since GCC 2.5 but GCC still accepts is to write `[index]` before the element value, with no `=`.
>
> To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write `[first ... last] = value`. For example,
>
> ```
>  int widths[] = { [0 ... 9] = 1, [10 ... 99] = 2, [100] = 3 };
> ```

**Note:** that the length of the array is the highest value specified plus one.

Additionally, we  can combine this technique of naming elements with ordinary C initialization of successive elements. Each initializer element that does not have a designator applies to the next consecutive element of the array or structure. For example:

```
 int a[6] = { [1] = v1, v2, [4] = v4 };
```

is equivalent to

```
 int a[6] = { 0, v1, v2, 0, v4, 0 };
```

Labeling the elements of an array initializer is especially useful when the indices are characters or belong to an enum type. For example:

```
 int whitespace[256]  = { [' '] = 1,  ['\t'] = 1, ['\h'] = 1,
                          ['\f'] = 1, ['\n'] = 1, ['\r'] = 1 
                        };
```

Comment: In your first example, `[3] = "bar";` - does that really set the third element (as you have shown) or index 3 (the fourth element) as would seem more natural?

Comment: @Vicky forth element, `[3] = "bar"` mean **3rd index**, Check [this working code](http://ideone.com/Z9CyPt)

Answer (score 8):

It's called **designated initializer** which is introduced in C99, gcc also supports it in GNU89 as an extension, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) for detail.

```
 int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 };
```

is equivalent to

```
 int a[6] = { 0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0 };
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a C99 *designated initializer*. the value in brackets specifies the index to receive the value.