# 2 Dim Array Assignment

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am trying to assign certain members of a 2 dim array. Not able to get following code to work. Help would appreciated very very much.

```
int myArray[5][5] = {[1][1]{1},[2][2]{2},[3][3]{3},[4][4]{4}};

main()
{
  printf("%d %d\n", myArray[1][1], myArray[4][4]);
}
```

Comment: In what way does the code not work?  Does it fail to compile, crash or give unexpected results?

Comment: I am getting following compile error 

array.c:3: error: expected ‘=’ before ‘{’ token
array.c:3: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘[’ token

Comment: haccks answer is only valid in c99: read:[Strange initializer expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329206/strange-initializer-expression/18329258#18329258)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are initializing the array

```
int myArray[5][5] = {[1][1]{1},[2][2]{2},[3][3]{3},[4][4]{4}};
```

is wrong. If you are interested in designator then initialize it as follows

```
int myArray[5][5] = {[1][1] = 1,[2][2] = 2,[3][3] = 3,[4][4] = 4};
```