# How to initialize an array of structures with variable index

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have structure like below

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} my_struct;
```

and in another file I have declared a variable of this `my_struct` type, like below.

```
my_struct strct_arr[MAX];
```

Where `MAX` is a macro which is a configurable value that is a multiple of 18 (18 or 36 or 54 and so on.. it may go up to 18*n times).

I have to initialize the structure with {0xff,0,0}. So, how to initialize whole array of structure `my_struct strct_arr[MAX];` with my initial values **without using any kind of loops.**

I am expecting the output as below:

```
my_struct strct_arr[MAX]={
    {0xff,0,0},
    {0xff,0,0},
    {0xff,0,0},
    {0xff,0,0},
    …
};
```

But without knowing `MAX` value, how to initialize it?

Comment: can you look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921559/initializing-array-of-structures

Comment: if 18, 36 or 54 are only options, then I would probably just write it with some `#ifdef`s.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/?kw=memset

Comment: @xmojmr His memory pattern rules out memset.

Comment: @xmojmr can you give example how we initializing above structure with `memset`?

Comment: @xmojmr memset can only used to set int value.

Comment: @Wilbeibi: Actually, `memset` can only be used to fill memory with `char` values. The parameter is declared with `int` type for purely historical reasons.

Answer (score 4):

There is GCC extension for this. Try this

```
#define MAX 18
my_struct strct_arr[MAX]={ [0 ... (MAX - 1)] = {0xff,0,0}};
```

Check https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible using the C preprocessor!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

#define INITS(z, n, t) { 0xFF, 0, 0 },
#define REP(item, n) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, INITS, item)

#define MAX 123

typedef struct { int a,b,c; } my_struct;

my_struct ms[] = { REP(, MAX) };

int main()
{
    // Check it worked
    printf("%d\n", (int)(sizeof ms / sizeof *ms));
}
```

Note: `boost` is a package of C++ stuff, however the `boost/preprocessor` just uses the preprocessor features which are common to both languages.  If your implementation doesn't allow this `#include` by default, you can find a copy of `repeat.hpp` from the boost source code.

Also, `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` defaults to a max of `256`. If your `MAX` is bigger than this, you can edit `repeat.hpp` to allow bigger values, it should be obvious what to do from there.

Note: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447557/can-we-have-recursive-macros) describes a system for recursive macro that would not require the same sort of implementation as `repeat.hpp` uses, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Credit: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551418/c-preprocessor-macro-for-returning-a-string-repeated-a-certain-number-of-times)

Comment: I knew there had to be a preprocessor solution.  The issue started with `#define MAX *something*`; a problem born in the preprocessor. The solution had to come from there too. ;)  And as I suspected, it's loathsome (yet I can't look away)!  +1 for not letting me down. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's is no direct and immediate syntax in *standard* C to specify an initializer that would do what you want. If you wanted to initialize the whole thing with zeros, then `= { 0 }` would work regardless of size, but that `0xff` makes it a completely different story. GCC compiler supports a non-standard extension that works in such cases (see Sanket Parmar's answers for details), but alas it is not standard.

There's also a non-standard `memcpy` hack that is sometimes used to fill memory regions with repetitive patterns. In your case it would look as follows

```
my_struct strct_arr[MAX] = { { 0xff, 0, 0 } };
memcpy(strct_arr + 1, strct_arr, sizeof strct_arr - sizeof *strct_arr);
```

But this is a hack, since it relies on `memcpy` doing its copying in byte-by-byte fashion and in strictly left-to-right direction (i.e. from smaller memory addresses to larger ones). However, that's not guaranteed by the language specification. If you want to "legalize" this trick, you have to write your own version of `my_memcpy` that works in that way specifically (byte-by-byte, left-to-right) and use it instead. Of course, this is formally a cyclic solution that is not based entirely on initializer syntax.

Comment: Even if this memcpy "works" it would be because the implementation of memcpy has a loop in it, so you lose nothing performance-wise by explicitly putting the loop in your own code.

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24288415):

```
struct my_struct { char c, int a; int b; }

#define MAX 135

#define INIT_X_1     { 0xff, 0, 0 }
#define INIT_X_2     INIT_X_1, INIT_X_1
#define INIT_X_4     INIT_X_2, INIT_X_2
#define INIT_X_8     INIT_X_4, INIT_X_4
#define INIT_X_16    INIT_X_8, INIT_X_8
#define INIT_X_32    INIT_X_16, INIT_X_16
#define INIT_X_64    INIT_X_32, INIT_X_32
#define INIT_X_128   INIT_X_64, INIT_X_64

struct my_struct strct_arr[MAX] =
{
#if (MAX & 1)
    INIT_X_1,
#endif
#if (MAX & 2)
    INIT_X_2,
#endif
#if (MAX & 4)
    INIT_X_4,
#endif
#if (MAX & 8)
    INIT_X_8,
#endif
#if (MAX & 16)
    INIT_X_16,
#endif
#if (MAX & 32)
    INIT_X_32,
#endif
#if (MAX & 64)
    INIT_X_64,
#endif
#if (MAX & 128)
    INIT_X_128,
#endif
};
```

Comment: Mr Wildplasser, This is the way I have tried it my self after some struggle. But the thing is, I cannot restrict my initialization up to 54 or 62 or even 128. It's really hard to get an idea on MAX number value which will be varied by the user configuration. So, I have created a perl script which will generate one macro based on the configured MAX value. In this way, I don't make C code burden in run time.

Comment: Well, it is not that hard to extend this solution to 512, 1024, ... and beyond. Everery doubling will only cost you a few (four) extra lines. But codegeneration is always an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of variety, since you know the array will be a multiple of 18, you could use something like this:

```
#define INIT_X_1     { 0xff, 0, 0 }
#define INIT_X_3     INIT_X_1, INIT_X_1, INIT_X_1
#define INIT_X_9     INIT_X_3, INIT_X_3, INIT_X_3
#define INIT_X_18    INIT_X_9, INIT_X_9

my_struct strct_arr[MAX] =
{
    INIT_X_18,
#if MAX > 18
    INIT_X_18,
#if MAX > 36
    INIT_X_18,
#endif
#endif
};
```

This will work without needing C99 support (it would even work with pre-standard C), GCC extensions, or Boost Preprocessor library.  In every other respect, the other solutions are better.

Comment: I see that you have considered it up to 54 times. I am afraid that if my array size is 64, will it initialize 64 times with structure values. Can you give any possibilities if I need to continue up to the max value, which is a configurable value?

Comment: Use [wildplasser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/905902/wildplasser)'s [generalization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24288670/15168) of my solution, as long as you have an upper bound to work with.  Otherwise, you'll need to use an extra-linguistic mechanism such as you mention in your comments below his answer.  I tailored my answer to the multiples of 18 you mentioned in your question.  Failing that, consider using  a single initializer and copying that to your array at runtime.  It won't take long compared to everything else that you're going to do.