# How to Initialise array of type struct with DOT operator

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize an array of type struct  within main() but compiler returns error `field designator cannot initialize a non-struct, non-union type` 
My Code:

```
struct details{
    const char *author;
    const char *title;
};


int main()
{
    const char *input = "Data Structures and Algorithm";
    struct details a [] = { 
        .author = "Narsimha", 
        .title = input
    };  
    printf("%s\n", a[0].author);
    printf("%s\n", a[0].title);

    return 0;
}
gcc inputs.c 
inputs.c:16:9: error: field designator cannot initialize a non-struct, non-union type 'struct details []'
        .author = "Narsimha", 
        ^
inputs.c:17:9: error: field designator cannot initialize a non-struct, non-union type 'struct details []'
        .title = input
        ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing array of structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921559/initializing-array-of-structures)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a pair of braces. Try with this:

```
struct details a [] = {{ 
        .author = "Narsimha", 
        .title = input
    }};
```

The outer braces are for defining an array. The inner braces are for the `struct`.